# How to apply the following rules to transform data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-cleaning

Hello I have the following text:

```
blood sampling were recor-
ded.

concentration [Cmax]
values available) in which subjects who administered

values around Cmax SCALE Diabetes (Trial 2) was a randomised, double-
blind, placebo-controlled, parallel group, multicentre,

considered pharmacokinetically relevant. However, gly-
caemic status was confounded by trial as all subjects with
```

I would like to transform this data to the following format one big line as follows:

```
blood sampling were recorded. concentration [Cmax] values available) in which subjects who administered values around Cmax SCALE Diabetes (Trial 2) was a randomised, double-blind, placebo-controlled, parallel group, multicentre, considered pharmacokinetically relevant. However, glycaemic status was confounded by trial as all subjects with
```

So I tried the following:

```
file = open('test.txt', 'r',encoding='utf-8') 

list_lines = []

for line in file:
    print(line)
    list_lines.append(line.replace('\n', ' ').replace('-\n', ''))

big_line = ''.join(list_lines)

text_file = open('changed.txt', "w",encoding='utf-8')
text_file.write(big_line)
text_file.close()
print('writing document')
```

However I just got:

```
blood sampling were recor- ded.  concentration [Cmax] values available) in which subjects who administered  values around Cmax SCALE Diabetes (Trial 2) was a randomised, double- blind, placebo-controlled, parallel group, multicentre,  considered pharmacokinetically relevant. However, gly- caemic status was confounded by trial as all subjects with
```

I can't find a way to automatize this task I have the following mistakes:

recor- ded
double- blind
gly- caemic

So I really would like to appreciate help to overcome this task I don`t know how to proceed, the main problem is that if I apply first one rule then I can't apply the second one since both are related to '\n'

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `re.sub` with a callback:

```
re.sub('-?\n+', lambda x: '' if '-' in x.group() else ' ', text)
```

This returns

> blood sampling were recorded. concentration [Cmax] values available)
>   in which subjects who administered values around Cmax SCALE Diabetes
>   (Trial 2) was a randomised, doubleblind, placebo-controlled, parallel
>   group, multicentre, considered pharmacokinetically relevant. However,
>   glycaemic status was confounded by trial as all subjects with

The pattern matches one or more newlines, preceded by an optional hyphen (`-`). The callback controls replacement. If the match contained a hyphen, it is treated as a continuation of the word on the next line. Otherwise, a space is inserted.

Comment: thanks however, 'double-blind'  is wrong in your example doubleblind

Comment: @neo33 How is the code supposed to know to treat that case specially? Please just live with it, or else you'd need to write something a LOT more complicated, using NLTK perhaps.

Comment: yes the problem is very complicated I have many words like that

Comment: @neo33 Then, your problem is too broad and cannot be reasonably solved within a single question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Using replace():

```
t = """blood sampling were recor-
ded.

concentration [Cmax]
values available) in which subjects who administered

values around Cmax SCALE Diabetes (Trial 2) was a randomised, double-
blind, placebo-controlled, parallel group, multicentre,

considered pharmacokinetically relevant. However, gly-
caemic status was confounded by trial as all subjects with"""

# uncomment for reading from file:
# with open('test.txt', 'r',encoding='utf-8') as doc:
#    lines = doc.read()

lines = t

line = lines.replace("- ","-").replace("-\n","").replace("\n"," ").replace("  "," ")

print(line)


with open('changed.txt', "w",encoding='utf-8') as text_file :
    text_file.write(line)
```

Output:

> blood sampling were recorded. concentration [Cmax] values available) in which subjects who administered values around Cmax SCALE Diabetes (Trial 2) was a randomised, doubleblind, placebo-controlled, parallel group, multicentre, considered pharmacokinetically relevant. However, glycaemic status was confounded by trial as all subjects with

Comment: thanks however, 'double-blind' is wrong in your example doubleblind

Comment: @neo it is not. There are limitations to what you can do automagically. Unless you provide a dictionary of hyphonated words that should NOT be de-hyphonated when breaked at the hyphen on a line, this is as much as any automated process can do. If you want semantical analysys use a lib like Natutral LanguageTool Kit (NLTK).

Comment: yes I know I was thinking if someone could have a creative way to overcome this